# How to conditionally assign value to a ViewModel property from within the View

Tags: angularjs

I have the following HTML that shows an error message when `ng-show` conditions are met. However, the `ng-init` assignment happens whether error message is shown or not.

```
<div ng-show="peopleworksForm.submitted && formData['DisclosureQuestion'+($index+1)+'Answer'] == 'true' && formData['DisclosureQuestion'+($index+1)+'OptionalAnswer'] == undefined" 
     ng-init="$parent.answerValFailed = true">
   invalid value
</div>
```

What I want is to do the operation inside `ng-init` only after `ng-show` conditions are met. Is there an easy way to do so?

Comment: Not related to the question, just an advice: don't do that "calculation" within your markup. Create a function, say, `canShow()` or `shouldShow()` and put that logic inside your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-if and inside it use ng-init :)

```
    <div class="pw-form-inline-error" ng-if="peopleworksForm.submited && formData['DisclosureQuestion'+($index+1)+'Answer'] == 'true' && formData['DisclosureQuestion'+($index+1)+'OptionalAnswer'] == undefined">
            <span ng-init="$parent.answerValFailed = true">
                            invalid value
              </span>
    </div>
```

Hope it helps :)